# Click on <li> from dropdown doesn't produce expected behavior from said click

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

**My Issue:**

I'm trying to write up a tampermonkey script to automate downloading an excel sheet. Currently, my script can load the page of relevance, tick filters, fill-out the form, and open up the drop-down for the list shown below. I have tried a few ways of selecting an element from that list but despite being able to click on the element it doesn't execute the expected behavior. It collapses the drop down list when a download window is supposed to pop up.

**What I tried:**

Looking through a few other stackoverflow posts, I tried a few things

*Document Selector*

```
let downloadDee = document.querySelector("#downloadDropdown_menu_item0");
                    downloadDee.click()
```

*jQuery Selector*

```
$('#downloadDropdown_menu_item0').click()
```

*Simulating a Mouse Event*

```
function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}

let downloadDee = document.querySelector("#downloadDropdown_menu_item0 > div");
                        if (downloadDee) {
                            //--- Simulate a natural mouse-click sequence.
                            triggerMouseEvent (downloadDee, "mouseover");
                            triggerMouseEvent (downloadDee, "mousedown");
                            triggerMouseEvent (downloadDee, "mouseup");
                            triggerMouseEvent (downloadDee, "click");
                        }
```

**Observation:**

Looking at the elements when I toggle the dropdown list it seems to dynamically add the list.

[image]

**Page Elements:**

```
<nav _ngcontent-tkv-c60="">
    <div _ngcontent-tkv-c60="" class="parent">
        <ul _ngcontent-tkv-c60="" id="downloadDropdown_menu_list">
            <li _ngcontent-tkv-c60="" ecnavitemactive="is-selected" class="item"
                id="downloadDropdown_menu_item0">
                <div _ngcontent-tkv-c60="" class="item-wrapper"><span _ngcontent-tkv-c60="" class="label"
                                                                      id="downloadDropdown_menu_item0_label">Excel data only</span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li _ngcontent-tkv-c60="" ecnavitemactive="is-selected" class="item"
                id="downloadDropdown_menu_item1">
                <div _ngcontent-tkv-c60="" class="item-wrapper"><span _ngcontent-tkv-c60="" class="label"
                                                                      id="downloadDropdown_menu_item1_label">Excel formatted</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p _ngcontent-tkv-c60="" class="no-data-message">No Items</p></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: $('#downloadDropdown_menu_item0').trigger("click"); ?

Comment: It didn't work but don't worry about it, I discovered selenium which seems to have a few extra bells and whistles along with being able to execute what I needed. Appreciate the attempt.